# Core Data Excessive VM: SQLite page cache

Tags: ios, sqlite, caching, core-data, virtual-memory

I will keep this question general for now and avoid cluttering this with code.

I have an iOS application that uses Core Data (`sqlite`) for its data store.  The model is fairly complex, with large hierarchy of objects.  When I fetch and import these large data sets I am noticing that the application shuts down after awhile due to a memory warning.

The Allocations profiler shows me excessive "transient" VM: `SQLite` page objects.   The size of this keeps growing and growing but NEVER goes down.   I have tried to ensure that all of my `NSManagedObjectContext` saves occur inside performBlock calls.

It would seem to me as if there are object contexts that are not getting deallocated and / or reset.

I have tried disabling undoManager in `NSManagedObjectContext`. setting the stalenessInterval to a very low value (1.0), and calling reset on my MOC's after they are done saving data upon import.

What does this mean when the transient VM `SQLite` page cache continues to go up so high? 
What needs to be done in order to make the page cache go down?
What is an acceptable size for this cache to get to in a large Core Data application?

Thanks,

Comment: Were you able to find some solution? I'm facing exactly the same issue..

Comment: Just answered the question below.

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out the transient VM SQLite page cache column show in Instruments is cumulative to the session, not the "current" value.  Well of course it never goes down then!

Turns out that some other optimizations around ensuring managed object contexts get cleared out fixed our CoreData memory issue.

Great article here on the subject: [Core Data issues with memory allocation](https://finalize.com/2013/01/04/core-data-issues-with-memory-allocation/)